# Multithreading use of XMemcached client

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, memcached, xmemcached

Given

```
client = new XMemcachedClient(server, port);
```

What happens if I have several thread doing this:

```
object = client.get(key);
```

In the (quite empty) [xmemcached javadoc](http://xmemcached.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/apidocs/net/rubyeye/xmemcached/MemcachedClient.html) I see no mention of synchronization.

1. is `MemcachedClient.get` synchronized? if not, have I got to synchronize it myself?
2. can calls to memcached be done in parallel, in order to avoid my threads to be blocked? Do I need to instanciate one `MemcachedClient` per thread or is the current code capable of this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*XMemcachedClient* can be used by many threads in paralel. There is not need to synchronize the calling to *XMemcachedClient* instance. Here's a sample [code](http://xmemcached.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/benchmark/) how many threads can use single client.

On the xmemcached page there's a [benchmark](http://xmemcached.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/benchmark/benchmark.html) which show performance depending on number of threads that use single *XMemcachedClient* instance.